# error at /image_upload/ OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor' > - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Tags: python, django, conv-neural-network

**Hello
I'm working on a web using django and I want to connect with the be cnn . model
But after uploading an image to be processed, this error appears
What's the problem? **

```
from django.http import request
from django.shortcuts import render ,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import Images
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
import h5py


def image_upload(request):
  data = {}
  form=Images(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
  data["info"]=form
  if request.POST:
    
    if form.is_valid():

        new_form = form.save(commit=False)
        new_form.user = request.user
        new_form.save()
        label_dict={0:'Covid19 Negative', 1:'Covid19 Positive'}
        img_size = 100
        path = 'C:/Users/Dr.Esraa/Desktop/project_covid/covid_19%s'% new_form.Image.url
        img = cv2.imread(path)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        resized = cv2.resize(gray ,(img_size , img_size) )
        data_array = np.array(resized)/255
        data = resized.reshape(-1,img_size,img_size,1)
        model_loded = load_model(r"C:\Users\Dr.Esraa\Desktop\project_covid\covid_19\test_img")
        predectied = model_loded.predict(data)
        result=np.argmax(predectied,axis=1)[0]
        accuracy=float(np.max(predectied,axis=1)[0])
        label=label_dict[result]


        data = {'label':label, 'result':result, 'accuracy':accuracy, 'url': 
        new_form.Image.url, 'info': form}

        return render(request, 'test_img/test.html', data)
return render(request, 'test_img/image_upload.html',data)


error at /image_upload/
```

OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/image_upload/
>   Django Version: 3.2.4
>   Exception Type: error
>   Exception Value:
>   OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor'
>   Overload resolution failed:
> - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
>   Exception Location: C:\Users\User\Desktop\project_covid\covid_19\test_img\views.py, line 34, in image_upload
>   Python Executable:  C:\Users\User\Desktop\project_covid\Scripts\python.exe
>   Python Version: 3.9.2
>   Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\User\Desktop\project_covid\covid_19',
>   'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip',
>   'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs',
>   'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib',
>   'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39',
>   'C:\Users\User\Desktop\project_covid',
>   'C:\Users\User\Desktop\project_covid\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\Users\User\Desktop\project_covid\lib\site-packages\win32',
>   'C:\Users\User\Desktop\project_covid\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
>   'C:\Users\User\Desktop\project_covid\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']
>   Server time:    Thu, 15 Jul 2021 15:52:13 +0000
>   Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\project_covid\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
>   response = get_response(request) …
>   ▶ Local vars
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\project_covid\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
>   response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
>   ▶ Local vars
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\project_covid\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py, line 21, in _wrapped_view
>   return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) …
>   ▶ Local vars
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\project_covid\covid_19\test_img\views.py, line 34, in image_upload
>   gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) …
>   ▶ Local vars